# Scala - Expression of type Object doesn't confirm to type String

Tags: scala

I am trying to make this trait as close to idiomatic Scala as possible:
My goal is to mix in this trait in `ScalaTest` class as

```
class MyTest extends FunSpect with Matchers With MyTrait
```

The trait itself:

```
import java.io.{FileFilter, File}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.{JsonNodeFactory, ArrayNode} 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{JsonNode, ObjectMapper} 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory

     trait TicketInfo_Json {
          var testJsonOpt: Option[JsonNode] = None
          var jsonFileOpt: Option[File] = None

          val testJson = {
            try {
                val jsonFile = new File(this.getClass.getResource("/ticketJson.json").getPath)
                testJsonOpt = if(jsonFile.exists() && jsonFile.isFile) Some(new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonFile)) else None
                testJsonOpt.get.toString
            } catch {
                case ioe: java.io.IOException => Some(new JsonNodeFactory(true).arrayNode()).get
            }

          }

           def getJson: String = testJson // Error: Expression of type Object doesn't confirm to type String

        }

    }
```

---

The goal is to be able to call the method `testJson`, and my hope is that the logic in the trait will process the `ticketJson.json` json file and return a json file via `getJson` back to my calling class. In this class, my Test Class.

However I am getting the error

`Expression of type Object doesn't confirm to type String`

The reason I am struggling to get this program right, is the fact that I am trying to stay away from vars, but I still cannot wrap my head around the best way to use vals. How would I use Options to good effect. My code has a strong code smell and I do not know how to approach this, as yet.

This is as far as I have got. How do I avoid the error aforementioned?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `catch` block return non-`String` value, so variable `testJson` has type `Object` instead of `String`. Try figure out what following code returns:

```
case ioe: java.io.IOException => Some(new JsonNodeFactory(true).arrayNode()).get
```

`try` section returns `String` and `catch` section return `ArrayNode`. So result type of `try-catch` block is the nearest superclass of `String` and `ArrayNode` and it will be `Object`.

Comment: To me, it looks like "Some(new JsonNodeFactory(true).arrayNode()).get" is returning an ArrayNode (an implementation of JsonNode). Okay, what I fail to understand is, how can it be of type Object, rather than ArrayNode?

Comment: @user3825558 Since the type of a try/catch is the lowest common supertype of the try and the catch; and the only supertype of both `String` and `ArrayNode` is `Object`. Additionally, `Some(foo).get` is quite useless, since that will always return `foo`.

Comment: Ah, that is quite an eye-opener.Can you explain this: Since the type of a try/catch is the lowest common supertype of the try and the catch;                 in a little more detail. I am going to mark your answer as correct

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. I did some research in the interim. Thanks for the time and effort

Comment: Awesome answer! This is quite indeed an eyeopener to me. Thanks much.

Comment: One last question: I am getting a NullPointerException at the line: val jsonFile = new File(this.getClass.getResource("/ticketJson.json").getPath) It is odd because the file ticketJson.json is in the classpath under src/main/resources/testFolder/ticketJson.json                                                     What do you think is happening?

Comment: @user3825558 Code `this.getClass` returns different resource path depends on class to which trait mixed in. Try `TicketInfo_Json.class` or absolute path to resource.

Comment: @user3825558 The technical term is "last upper bound". Since the statement must have one type, Scala chooses a super type of both to stay type safe; if there is more than one super type, it chooses the most precise (= lowest) one.

Comment: Very informed answer. I was reading up the scalla documentation and what you say makes more sense now